# Change the value from string to number and calculate a new result extracting the number with comas and currency(Vuex)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I need to calculate a new number and then extract It with comas and the currency on the Vuex Store... here is the code

```
export default {
  addRegister(state, payload) {
    const registerToUpdate = state.registers.find(
      (register) => register.id === payload.id
    );

    const currency = registerToUpdate.currency;
    const expenses = registerToUpdate.expense;

    //Opcion C  (funciona)
    let total = registerToUpdate.currentSalar - payload.salary;

     if (typeof registerToUpdate.currentSalar === "string") {
      parseFloat(registerToUpdate.currentSalar);
      
      total = registerToUpdate.currentSalar - payload.salary;
      
      registerToUpdate.currentSalar = new Intl.NumberFormat("il-IL", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: currency,
      }).format(total);
      
      payload.salary = new Intl.NumberFormat("il-IL", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: currency,
      }).format(payload.salary);
      
      console.log(typeof registerToUpdate.currentSalar, typeof payload.salary);
      console.log('total:', registerToUpdate.currentSalar, 'salary: ', payload.salary);
    } else { 
      
      registerToUpdate.currentSalar = new Intl.NumberFormat("il-IL", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: currency,
    }).format(total);
    
    payload.salary = new Intl.NumberFormat("il-IL", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: currency,
    }).format(payload.salary);

    console.log(typeof registerToUpdate.currentSalar, typeof payload.salary);
    console.log('total:', registerToUpdate.currentSalar, 'salary: ', payload.salary);
  }

    expenses.unshift(payload);
  },
};
```

In the first Place on the Vuex store the `currentSalar` is defined to a Number and after inserting an expense(`payload.salary`) it's give me the result I want but when I insert a second expense it's give me Nan cause the `currentSalar` defined to a string.

Comment: as a best practice you should always store and work with all currency/salary amounts as numbers.  you only need to convert to strings with commas, currency symbols, etc. when displaying to the UI

Comment: this is what I'm trying to do, do you have any suggestions how to achive this?